How to save data change history modified with JPA saveAll using Hibernate CustomEventListener
We are implementing the data change history function using Hibernate CustomEventListener. Detects when values ​​are modified through JPA's save or saveAll through PostUpdateEventListener.
@Slf4j
@Component
public class CustomPostUpdateEventListener implements PostUpdateEventListener {
  @Override
  public void onPostUpdate(PostUpdateEvent event) {
     if (!Objects.equals(beforeValue, afterValue)) {
        entityManager.persist(ChangeData.builder()
         .before(beforeVal)
         .after(afterVal)
         .build());     
     }
  }
}

Currently, we are loading the change history log by inheriting PostUpdateEventListener, creating a class, comparing change values ​​within the onPostUpdate() method, and saving the change history to RDB using the changeDataRepository.save() code.
Values ​​using JPA's save method are loaded properly, but when the saveAll method is used, the data is not loaded into the changeData table. When I log the query, I see that when using save, the insert query loaded into the changeData table works well, but when saveAll is used, the insert query loaded into the changeData table is not executed.
I thought the problem was caused by not committing when saving the change history, so I added @Transaction to the save method that creates and saves the change history-related service, but the error situation was not resolved.
How can the change history of data modified with saveAll be properly loaded into the changeData table?

Just a note. There is a project Hibernate Envers (https://hibernate.org/orm/envers/) which already solves the task of saving changes history.
